# Provide Dynamic ID in jQuery inside XSLT

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xslt

I want to add my jQuery code inside my XSLT, that isn't the problem, the problem is....I need to provide Dynamic ID in my jQuery code.

I am using XSLT's variable to provide it but don't know exactly what should be the correct way??!!

Here is my Sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="groups" select="//rs:data//z:row[not(@GroupName=preceding-sibling::z:row/@GroupName)]"  />
<xsl:key name="k1" match="Users/User" use="@Name"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="$groups">

<script type="text/javascript">
function togglesetup_0() {
    jQuery('#@Name .contacts_basic').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).parent().children('div.contacts_basic2 > div.contacts_basic1').slideToggle();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('contacts_basic_selected');
    });
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("gmis_contacswp_togglesetup_0");
</script>

  <xsl:sort select="@GroupName" order="descending" />
  <xsl:sort select="@User" order="ascending" />
  <xsl:variable name="group" select="@GroupName" />

.....
  ......
```

Read this line...

```
jQuery('#@Name .contacts_basic').click(function () {
```

I need to provide a dynamic ID where I have written @Name (an XSLT Variable).

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function togglesetup_0() {
    jQuery('#<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>.contacts_basic').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).parent().children('div.contacts_basic2 > div.contacts_basic1').slideToggle();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('contacts_basic_selected');
    });
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("gmis_contacswp_togglesetup_0");
</script>
```

Another point concerning your code : the sort element must comme just after the for-each.

To generate id with XSLT, you have the `generate-id()` function. I you don't have any argument it returns a unique id for the context node. In our case, if you replace `@Name` in select attribute in the code above with generate-id().

If you use it at another place in the XSLT, it will produce the same id if you are in the same context or if you give the right context node as an argument `generate-id(myNode)`. You can replace the `myNode` by any XPath function that return a nodeset.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, it's working fine...Can I provide ny Random number into it??  I also want to use the same number in HTML outside this <script> tag.

Comment: Could you please write sample of how to use it?

Comment: And I also want to use the same generated ID in my HTML code outside that script tag...!!